# SSIS issue with excel import

Tags: excel, import, ssis

i have a package that connects to an excel file with 2 tabs.

Tab 1 has 700 rows
Tab 2 has 12000 rows

so within the package i have to dataflows, one for each tab.

All this works fine when running locally in Visual Studio.

BUT, when i deploy to Integration Services Catalog then create an agent job.
The agent job always fails on the tab 2 which has 12K rows.

The first tab always works fine.

I have the agent job set to run in 32bit, which is what i always do with an excel doc import.

Also i have set delay validation where i can in the package.

Does anyone have any suggestions please. Its driving me nuts LOL

Kind Regards

Rob

Comment: What is the error recorded in the ssisdb?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM SSISDB.catalog.operation_messages AS OM WHERE OM.message_type = 120 AND OM.operation_id = 1234` where 1234 is the execution id of a failing run

Comment: when i look at the above view, there is nothing related to execution of the job.
Also when i look at the reports of the catalog all i can see is unexpected termination, no error messages or any good information to help.

Comment: I have also used the import and export wizard to create the package for me, then deploy that to Catalog Services, then run via agent,  I still get the no helpful errors or information just the usual Unexpected Termination.  So frustrating, the excel file only has 12k rows.

Comment: message_type of 120 is an error so it sounds like the package isn't even passing a basic validation check. Let's try that - right click on package or project in the Integration Services Node and there should be a validate packages option - let that run and see if there's something abnormal

Answer (score 0):

The default data import package of sql server is 32 bit,so you must change sql server agent job step properties run time to 32 bit. In Job Step Properties, go to Configuration tab and check 32-bit runtime box.